# JsViews doesn't seem to work with numeric properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsviews

When I try to pass JavaScript object with numeric properties

```
{ 1: "One", 2: "Two", 3: "Three" }
```

Data-binding doesn't render property values, only numbers like in example

```js
$.templates("template", "#template");
$.link.template("#row", { 1: "One", 2: "Two", 3: "Three" });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jsviews.min.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <td>{{:1}}</td>
  <td>{{:2}}</td>
  <td>{{:3}}</td>
</script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
  </tr>
</table>
```

But if I change property names of object to something beginning with letter it works OK

```js
$.templates("template", "#template");
$.link.template("#row", { n1: "One", n2: "Two", n3: "Three" });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jsviews.min.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <td>{{:n1}}</td>
  <td>{{:n2}}</td>
  <td>{{:n3}}</td>
</script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it bug or feature? How to make jsViews work with numeric properties without converting passed object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write `{{:4}}` for some integer, then JsRender treats that as an expression, and evaluates it. (For example `{{:4*12+2}}` will render `50`).

In JavaScript if an object property name (key) is not a valid identifier name you have to use the square bracket accessor syntax.

In JsRender/JsViews templates, the same is true. (See [www.jsviews.com/#paths](https://www.jsviews.com/#paths)).

Here are multiple examples:

```js
$.templates("template", "#template");
$.link.template("#row",
 { 1: "One", "2": "Two", 3: "Three", other: { 50: "fifty" }, 4: { 5: "five"}, "a b": "AB" });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jsviews.min.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <td>{{:#data[1]}}</td>
  <td>{{:#data[1+1]}}</td>
  <td>{{:#data["3"]}}</td>
  <td>{{:other[50]}}</td>
  <td>{{:~root[1]}}</td>
  <td>{{:#data[4]["5"]}}</td>
  <td>{{:#data["a b"]}}</td>
</script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [JSRender/JSView](https://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag) 
Here if you see last section **Sample: {{:#index ...}}**, it uses index of json object and same is happening when you use numbers as key in json object and try to map it in template, hence template it treating it as index and not key.
Better user some static letter with number like key1, key2.. etc.

```js
$.templates("template", "#template");
$.link.template("#row", {key1: "One", key2: "Two", key3: "Three" });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jsviews.min.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <td>{{:key1}}</td>
  <td>{{:key2}}</td>
  <td>{{:key3}}</td>
</script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use string just like below.

```
{ "1": "One", "2": "Two", "3": "Three" }
```